# Mixing pages and categories in menu - permalink problems

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have/want the structure:

```
News
NewsPage | AnotherNewsPage | NewsCategory1 | NewsCategory2
NewsPost1 etc
```

Permalinks should be `/news/newspage` (works), `/news/newscategory1` (doesn't work / permalink collision), `news/newscategory1/newspost1` etc/

I currently have it so that `News` is a standard page as opposed to the Posts Page.

If this possible? Or do I have to accept that the permalinks for posts will always be different from the page permalinks / not mix pages and posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permalink of the post will always be different - unless you start using custom post types and taxonomies.

You can change the root of the category path in the permalink settings - this will change the path for all posts though.

You could also start messing with rewrite rules but this could break everything else.